# Access to Bigquery database

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am taking the google cert course in data analytics and am having problems with bigquery. I am getting an error message saying I don't have access to the public database.  Any suggestions to what is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT 
usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) as num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_.citybike_trips`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

this is the error I keep getting
Access Denied: Table bigquery-public-data:new_york_.citybike_trips: User does not have permission to query table bigquery-public-data:new_york_.citybike_trips.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below:

```
SELECT 
usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) as num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It appears that this is the correct table name: `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` or `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips` if you meant this dataset